# getnewaddress with importmulti

Tags: output-script-descriptors, importmulti

I have a question about how the bitcoin core wallet works with descriptors.

I am creating a wallet using the `createwallet` method and passing in a name (all other args are default).

I then import addresses into Bitcoin Core using `importmulti` and `wsh(sortedmulti(2,[abc123ef/48h/0h/0h/2h]xpubyadayada.../0/*, [abc345ef/48h/0h/0h/2h]xpubyadaya1da.../0/*, [abc567ef/48h/0h/0h/2h]xpubyadaya2da.../0/*))#checksum`

When I run `deriveaddresses` with `wsh(sortedmulti(2,[abc123ef/48h/0h/0h/2h]xpubyadayada.../0/*, [abc345ef/48h/0h/0h/2h]xpubyadaya1da.../0/*, [abc567ef/48h/0h/0h/2h]xpubyadaya2da.../0/*))#checksum` I get the expected addresses as an output but when I run the `getnewaddress` command after running `importmulti`, I get an address but not any of the addresses that were output from `deriveaddresses`.

I then noticed there is a `disable_private_keys` option when creating the wallet, so I've setup a new wallet using that flag.

I go through the setup process again with `keypool=true` when importing multi but when I run `getnewaddress` I get `"Error: This wallet has no available keys"`. The importmulti call returns `success: true`, and I get `Already have script 522103b403e66...` in my logs when I try running the command twice.

Does `getnewaddress` not work with descriptors? Or am I setting up the wallet incorrectly? I see there is an argument `blank` to pass in when creating a wallet but when I try that and import I get `Error: This wallet has no available keys` too.

I would expect `getnewaddress` to output the first address returned from `deriveaddresses` on a fresh wallet. Have I overlooked something in the documentation?

I looked at these docs too and I think I've followed them exactly:
https://gist.github.com/achow101/a9cf757d45df56753fae9d65db4d6e1d

[Using importmulti with internal set to true does not add any change keys. What am I doing wrong?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88520/using-importmulti-with-internal-set-to-true-does-not-add-any-change-keys-what-a?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Import multisig change addresses into Bitcoin Core using "importmulti" + descriptor](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89114/import-multisig-change-addresses-into-bitcoin-core-using-importmulti-descrip)

[What is the best way to create a wallet with a blank keypool then add keys to it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87629/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-wallet-with-a-blank-keypool-then-add-keys-to-it)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, did you find out how to make it work? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getnewaddress` on non-descriptor wallets does not work for non-single key things. Ad descriptor wallets have not yet been released, you are not using a descriptor wallet. When you use `importmulti` to import a descriptor, it does not actually import the descriptor. Rather it uses the descriptor to construct a bunch of keys and scripts and imports them into the wallet. However this does not mean that those scripts will be accessible with `getnewaddress`. They are just in the wallet as being watched.

You aren't doing anything wrong, `getnewaddress` just doesn't work like that for non-descriptor wallets.

If you make a `descriptor` wallet (using one of the 0.21.0 release candidates, or a build of the master branch), then `getnewaddress` will work as you expect it to.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for clearing that up. I am running 0.20.1, so that makes sense why it isn't working as expected. When you say they are just in the wallet as being watched, does that mean I can still monitor transactions for those addresses using the flow I used above? I haven't rescanned the blockchain yet because I wanted to make sure the addresses I was importing were correct.